# Access Report groupig by expression

Tags: ms-access

I want to group in my report by value [Order] with exception: if value of [tmp] is equal to 1, they should be grouped together with extra header

I tried

```
=IIf([tmp]=1;1;[Order])
```

but it just gives an error "This expression is typed incorrectly ...", basically every expression in grouping with **IIf** function gives that error, works fine in other parts of access

when i just put

```
=[Order]
```

it's fine

Is it just me who don't understand something about how expressions or grouping in access works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For grouping in a query there are two possibilites:

1. Use a UNION query:

   ```
   SELECT Max(YourField) FROM YourTable WHERE Tmp <> 1 GROUP BY [Order]
   UNION
   SELECT Max(YourField) FROM YourTable WHERE Tmp = 1 GROUP BY Tmp
   ```
2. Use a sub query to create a 'GroupField' based on your condition:

   ```
   SELECT Max(YourField)
   FROM (SELECT *, IIf(Tmp = 1, 1, [Order]) As GroupField FROM YourTable) As SubQuery
   GROUP BY GroupField
   ```

#### For grouping only in the report:

You can use the sub query as the record source of your report and then group on the 'virtual' field `GroupField`:

```
SELECT *, IIf(Tmp = 1, 1, [Order]) As GroupField FROM YourTable
```

#### Info:

`Max(YourField)` and `YourTable` are just to get my test query running, because you didn't specify the rest of your query.

Comment: Grouping in report is not the same as grouping in query, i want to print report that has all the elements, but each order will be separated by horizontal line

Comment: Ok, but you could use the sub query of my sample as the record source of your report, and then group in the report based on `GroupField`.

Comment: how? i need every record in table to be on the report, how can i group in query, when doing that will skip/contract different records together instead of getting them all printer out 'in specific order'

Comment: As I wrote, use the sub query (only) `SELECT *, IIf(Tmp = 1, 1, [Order]) As GroupField FROM YourTable` as the source for the report. It contains the created 'virtual' field `GroupField` which you can use then in the report for grouping. I will edit my answer.